# Giant magnetic something behind drywall/fireplace

Tags: fireplace, mounting, studs

I'm trying to mount a flatscreen TV above our fireplace that was converted by a previous owner (from wood?) to direct vent. During the process of finding the studs, I noticed that magnets stick the wall in a *continuous rectangle,* not in discreet spots like one might expect drywall nails to be. In the picture below, I put magnets in some places; again, they actually stick in between all of the places.

[image]

Notice that the rectangle is off-center with respect to the fireplace.

Here is the picture of the other side of the wall:

[image]

Any ideas what might be behind there? And any ideas how I might go about mounting the TV bracket?

Comment: MAGNETIC MOUNT!!! :-p

Comment: Pretty hard to tell, but my guess is that it was some sort of heat shield\dissipater or possibly a frame for the flue mechanism.